# define a function with parameter based on another javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have some common js functions with parameter, which I will reuse, so I thought, that I create another js file and store the common code here and in the target html I define these functions with parameters and if the functions are called, then they are executed.

I have this common function in a separate js file:

```js
function add_onClick(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
    }).done(function (response) {
        var popup = $("#entity-popup").dxPopup("instance");
        popup.option("contentTemplate", function (content) {
            content.append(response);
        });
        popup.show();
    });
}
```

If I define the function in the target html like this:

```
var add_onClick = add_onClick('/MasterData/Sender/NewSender')
```

then the function is executed on every page load, not on button click.

If I define the function like this:

```
var add_onClick = function () { add_onClick('/MasterData/Sender/NewSender'); };
```

Then I get the error 'javascript maximum call stack size exceeded'.

How should I define the function in the target html in order to execute only if the user clicks the add button?

Unexplaninable extra request:

[image]

**EDIT:**

The `/MasterData/Sender/NewSender` targets an action, which returns a view with a new `Sender` object like this:

```
public IActionResult NewSender()
    {
        ViewBag.Mode = "new";
        Sender Sender = new Sender();
        return PartialView("Sender", Sender);
    }
```

I think, this should be the extra traffic in the network window. But I don't get this extra line, if the `add_onClick` function isn't in a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

```
var add_onClick = function () { add_onClick('/MasterData/Sender/NewSender'); };
```

This is an infinite loop. It just continuously calls itself.

Maybe like this?

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  add_onClick('/MasterData/Sender/NewSender')
})

<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Yes, I already realized this, because I searched the error message. But the question remains.

Comment: Well, it works, but now in the console I get this: `https://localhost:44355/MasterData/Sender/[object%20Object]`, status code 404. This is a bit strange, because the called view appears correctly. Have you an idea why I get this error?

Comment: Does the `url` contain what you want it to? Does the `response` contain what you want it to? `console.log` both and debug from there.

Comment: Add a `catch` function to the ajax call. Perhaps that can help you a bit with error handling.

Comment: Yes, the url contains the right string and the response too. I have added a picture to the post, where we can see, that we have an extra request with this object thing. And of course in the controller there is no such action method and that's why I get 404 error (also tested with catch function).

Comment: Somewhere you are sending in an object to the url. You need to double check your code.